# WURFL's New API Question

Tags: php, api, caching, wurfl

I have a simple stupid question. Here's the problem, for years, my company has been using the old WURFL PHP API. Now, with the release of the new WURFL PHP API that promises a better performance, we want to use it.

What I want to ask is, **how do I update the cache? Can I use the old *update_cache.php***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several day searching for answer, it turns out that I can't use the old update_cache.php as it's incompatible to the NEW API.
The new API have the auto refresh mechanism when it see the wurfl.xml is changed/updated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about performance, you should look at [Tera-WURFL](http://www.tera-wurfl.com), it was built on the new WURFL API and uses MySQL to provide extremely high device detection performance.